# AngularJs: ng-repeat="item in arrayValue"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following array:

```
 var date = {
   '2015': [{
     'month': 'Januar',
     'day': 31
   }, {
     'month': 'Februar',
     'day': 28
   }]
 };
```

And I would like to make a ng-repeat equals to the number of days:
Output needed:

```
<div ng-repeat="date in date.2015">
  {{date.month}}
  <!-- Displays 12 month name -->
  <div ng-repeat="day in date.2015+{{$index}}+'.day'">
    {{day}}
    <!-- displays 31, 30 or 28 times the day -->
    <!-- The day should also increment from 0 to the number -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this is clear.
`ng-repeat="day in date.2015+{{$index}}+'.day'"` does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need a helper function in your controller that converts your number to an array with the length equal to that of your day's value:

```
$scope.range = function(n) {
    return new Array(n);   
}
```

If you're using the latest versions of angular, you will need to explicitly set a variable in the repeat to alias. [Working fiddle with the code you provided](https://jsfiddle.net/07osg7ae/)

```
<div ng-repeat="date in date.2015">
   {{date.month}} <!-- Displays 12 month name -->
   <div ng-repeat="day in range(date.day) track by $index">
        {{$index + 1}} <!-- displays 31, 30 or 28 times the day -->
        <!-- The day should also increment from 0 to the number -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Then you need to adjust your second `ng-repeat` to utilize the controller's  function to grab the index of the `ng-repeat` and add 1 since it's 0 based. [Working Plunker with old version](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wl5JDFycyQktUb8kKseM?p=preview)

```
<div ng-repeat="date in date.2015">
   {{date.month}} <!-- Displays 12 month name -->
   <div ng-repeat="day in range(date.day)">
        {{$index + 1}} <!-- displays 31, 30 or 28 times the day -->
        <!-- The day should also increment from 0 to the number -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated answer with your [forked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/07osg7ae/) @gr3g & snippet with latest angular example

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. The following problem is discribed here if interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651453/angularjs-creating-a-calender

Answer (score 0):

I hope I get it right what you want to do. To repeat the days do the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="date in date.2015">
   {{date.month}} <!-- Displays 12 month name -->
   <div ng-repeat="day in getDays(date.day)">
        {{day}} <!-- displays 31, 30 or 28 times the day -->
        <!-- The day should also increment from 0 to the number -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Now, just add this function in your controller:

```
$scope.getDays = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);   
}
```

Comment: He throws me an error. When using `ng-repeat="day in date.2015[0].day"`, the element isn't repeated, but no error